# Show Element on given x-y coordinate every few ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I have a function that, recieves `xy` coordinates from another client in my `SignalR` hub. whenever `clientA` moves his mouse, his `xy-coordinate` is sent to `ClientB`.

I am trying to print a simple `@` in the screen of `clientB` at that `x-y` coordinate. This works, but the only problem is that it is super slow (I think because the function gets called for every time the mouse moves `1px`). When i move my mouse on `clientA` for a few seconds, the printed "@" on `clientB`'s screen is falling behind.

Has this anything to do with the code i wrote to display this `@`?

```
hub.client.MouseMoved = function (x, y, id) {
        id = "@"; //for testing purposes
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        
        if (!e) { //if e is not found, create e
            e = $('<div id="' + id + '">' + id + '</div>');
            e.css('position', 'absolute');
            console.dir(e);
            $(e).appendTo(document.body);
        }
        else {
            e = $(e);
        }
            e.css({ left: x + "px", top: y + "px" }); //set position of cursor to x y coordinate.
        }
    }
```

Comment: use setInterval for this.

Comment: i tried to set a setInterval around this function. but it doesn't seem to react on that.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent low performance, you can use a timer :

```
var timer;

function executeMouseMoved(x, y, id){
    id = "@"; //for testing purposes
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
        
    if (!e) { //if e is not found, create e
        e = $('<div id="' + id + '">' + id + '</div>');
        e.css('position', 'absolute');
        console.dir(e);
        $(e).appendTo(document.body);
    }
    else {
        e = $(e);
    }
    e.css({ left: x + "px", top: y + "px" }); //set position of cursor to x y coordinate.
}

hub.client.MouseMoved = function (x, y, id) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){executeMouseMoved(x,y,id);}, 50); //50ms
}
```

Hope it helps.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqb5uu1x/4/)

Comment: i thought that worked. but it seemed just as slow. so i changed the interval from 50 to 1000. but it still executes the function every time and not every 1000ms. you declare "timer" and you clear the interval of the timer. isn't there anyhting else you are supposed to do with the timer?

Comment: Yes sorry, i've just forgot to instatiate the timer :). I hav updated the code.

Comment: but even if i instantiate it, it still doesn't fire every second.

Comment: If you let 50ms, the executeMouseMoved method will be executed 50ms after le last mouse mouve pixel was triggered instead of each time mouse move of 1 pixel

Comment: but it doesn't do that.  it still fires every moved pixel. even if i set the interval back to 50ms

Comment: now it must be correct. Sorry i haven't tested the code before ;)

Comment: The event now even fires if i don't move the mouse at all.. all the events now seem to fire after 50ms. so the function now gets called just as many times as before. only with 50ms timeout between the function calls.

Comment: have a look to the JsFiddle pls :)

Comment: But the x/y doesn't update if you keep moving your mouse. Only if you stop

Comment: Of course, it's the only way I know to prevent perfs issues... You can just reduce the timer time (near 1-2ms) to be more sensitive. Sorry